# Prove that any closed irreducible subset of $\mathrm {Spec} (R)$ has a unique generic point.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, proof-writing

> > Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. Let $X= \mathrm {Spec} (R).$ Let $A \subseteq X$ be a closed irreducible subset of $X.$ Then $A$ has a unique generic point.

I have proved the uniqueness part but can't prove the existence part of the above theorem. Uniqueness part is easy and I have proved it in the following way $:$

Let $p \in A$ be the generic point of $A.$ Then $A= \overline {\{p \}} = V(\mathcal {I} (\{p \})),$ (where $\mathcal {I} (A)$ is the vanishing ideal of $A$ for any subset $A$ of $\mathrm {Spec} (R)$ and for any ideal $I$ of $R,$ $V(I)$ is the zero set of the ideal $I$ in $\mathrm {Spec} (R)$). So we have $A = V(p) \implies \mathcal {I} (A) = \mathcal {I} (V (p)) = \sqrt {p} = p,$ since $p$ is a prime ideal of $R.$ This proves that $p = \bigcap\limits_{q \in A} q.$

So in order to show the existence of such generic point we need only to prove  that $\bigcap\limits_{q \in A} q \in A.$ But how can I show that? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A=Spec(R/I)$ is irreducible is and only $0$ is a prime ideal of $R/I$, so $\cap_{p\in Spec(R/I)}p=0$. Another way to say that $A$ is irreducible $A=V(I)$ if $I$ is a prime since every prime in $V(I)$ contains $I$, we deduce that $\cap_{p\in V(I)}p=I$ and $I$ is the generic point.

Comment: $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C[x]/(x^2))$ is irreducible (it's a single point), but $0$ is not a prime ideal in $\mathbb C[x]/(x^2)$. Are you sure you've got the first claim right?

Comment: But why do you take $I$ to be a prime ideal. Since $A$ is closed then definitely $A= V(I),$ for some ideal $I$ of $R.$ But it is not quite clear to me as to why $I$ is necessarily a prime ideal. Would you please clear it to me @Tsemo Aristide? Do you use irreducibility of $A$ here to conclude that?

Comment: Now I have understood. Since $A$ is irreducible $\mathcal {I} (A)$ is a prime ideal of $R.$ Also we know that $\overline {A} = V (\mathcal {I} (A)).$ Since $A$ is also closed so $A = V (\mathcal {I} (A)).$ So we can find a prime ideal $I$ of $R$ such that $A= V(I),$ where $I = \mathcal {I} (A).$ But since $I$ is prime so $I \in V(I) = A \implies \mathcal {I} (A) \in A \implies p \in A,$ as claimed.